# Error in findmnt

Tags: automounting

I'm writing a backup script prompting the user to insert (mount) a given backup USB stick if it is not mounted. For this I use `findmnt --source UUID="my uuid" --poll=mount --first-only`. It works fine but after inserting and automatically mounting the USB stick, I always get the error

> *** Error in `findmnt': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000c05040 ***

(with varying addresses). Although this is no problem for my particular script, I'm wondering if this is a bug in findmnt or am I missing something here?

Comment: Looks like a bug... I'm able to replicate this when using `poll=mount` with any of _UUID_, _LABEL_, _mountpoint_, _device_, _maj:min_. No error when used with `poll=umount`...

Comment: This message indicates a bug in the program (or in a library that it uses, or in your kernel or in your hardware). Have you searched the bug list for your distribution and for util-linux? What version of util-linux is this, on what distribution, running on what architecture?

Comment: @Gilles: Architecture: amd64, Version: 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20, Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic. I have searched [this bug list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux?field.searchtext=findmnt&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=) with no result.

Comment: Same bug here :(